# Webpack, extract-loader doesn't load load background url

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, sass

I'm having trouble with extract-loader. I try to add background: url(../../assets/icons/upload.svg); to sass, but I get an error.

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../assets/icons/upload.svg' from '/home/jeremy/code/sample-project/src/styles'
```

Tried resolve-url-loader, but without success.
My webpack config:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
        ],
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.hbs$/,
        loader: require.resolve('handlebars-loader'),
        query: {
          inlineRequires: '/assets/',
        },
      },
      {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                        options: {
                            name: 'main.css',
                        }
                    },
                    require.resolve('extract-loader'),
                    require.resolve('css-loader'),
                    require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                    require.resolve('sass-loader'),
                ],
            }
    ]
  },
```